# two columns with a vertical line between two columns using parallel package

Tags: two-column, parallel

I am wondering how it is possible to write in two columns which are separated with a vertical line and I wanna use the parallel package. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Option `v` of environment `Parallel` adds vertical line between left- and right-columns, see the [documentation of `parallel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/parallel/parallel.pdf), sec. 1.2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{.45\linewidth}{.45\linewidth}
\ParallelLText{<left-text>}
\ParallelRText{<right-text>}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{<left-text>}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much